# Listar registros ajax php

Tags: php, ajax

Pues mediante ajax mando una serie de datos y consigo acceder a los registros que quiero. Se trata de listar las reuniones que se hayan celebrado entre una fecha y otra:

```
public function allMeetingsBetweenDates($from, $to)
{
    $consulta = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM reunion WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");
    $arrayReuniones = array();
    foreach ($consulta->fetchAll() as $reu) {
        $arrayReuniones[] = array(
        'id' => $reu['id'],
        'asunto' => $reu['asunto'],
        'fecha' => $reu['fecha'],
        'coste_estimado' => $reu['costeEstimado'],
        );
    }
    $respuesta = array(
      'arrayReuniones' => $arrayReuniones
    );

    print_r($respuesta);
}
```

Lo que me devuelve es lo siguiente:

```
    Array
(
    [arrayReuniones] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 41
                    [asunto] => Material
                    [fecha] => 2020-03-03
                    [coste_estimado] => 21.67
                )

        )

)
```

Ahora en el js:

```
 success: function(dataArray) {
console.log(dataArray);
console.log(dataArray.arrayReuniones); //esto me devuelve undefined
var data = dataArray.result.arrayReuniones; //esto me da error porque la línea anterior da undefined
```

No entra en el if

```
if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data.length > 0) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value.id);
        console.log(value.asunto);
        console.log(value.fecha);
        console.log(value.observaciones);
        console.log(value.costo_estimado);
        // en esta parte haces lo que quieras con tus datos que 
        obtuviste en tu arreglo
    });
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Donde quieres mostrar los datos en una tabla, en un modal, en una ventana?

Comment: Los voy a mostrar en una tabla pero por el momento no sé cómo va a quedar así que es suficiente con lograr que me devuelva un json con cada propiedad de manera que pueda acceder a ellas a través de la respuesta y pintarlas en el log (ej: console.log(response.asunto)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente estás haciendo tu código complicado sin necesidad. Este tipo de problemas se podrían resolver de una forma muy sencilla:

1. En la petición Ajax indicas que quieres un `dataType: 'json'` que luego podrás leer adecuadamente en el `success` (lo cambiaremos por `done` porque `success` está obsoleto).
2. En PHP creas un grupo de objetos JSON y los devuelves al cliente. En ese punto, decir que hay una forma más simple de leer los datos.

Vamos a verlo en código:

### Javascript

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'aquiLaURL',
        method: 'POST',
        data: mData,    //sustituye tu variable mData por la de los datos
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    request.done(function(response) {
        /*
            Debido a la simplificad que aplicamos en PHP
            podremos leer los datos aquí con suma facilidad con un simple bucle
        */
        $.each(response, function (index,item) {
            console.log(`${item.id} - ${item.asunto}  - ${item.fecha} - ${item.costeEstimado}\n`);
        });
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Error en la petición: " + textStatus);
    });
```

### PHP

Vamos a aprovechar para implementar consultas preparadas, dando seguridad al código.

Dado que trabajaremos con un json, emitiremos un json  al cliente para que éste pueda leerlo con facilidad.

Nótese la forma natural de traer los datos, para evitar complicaciones, hemos dejado las columnas tal cual y así las leeremos en el cliente. En este código el array se crearía de forma natural usando los nombres de las columnas. No hay necesidad de complicarse la vida, creando código redundante.

```
public function allMeetingsBetweenDates($from, $to)
{
    #Escribimos una consulta preparada con marcadores
    $sql="SELECT id,asunto,fecha,costeEstimado FROM reunion WHERE fecha BETWEEN :from AND :to";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    #Creamos un array que asocia marcadores y datos
    $mParams=array(':from'=>$from, ':to'=>$to);
    #Lo pasamos aquí para neutralizar ataques de hackers
    $stmt->execute($mParams);
    $arrayReuniones = array();
    #Implementamos una lectura más natural y más ligera
    while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        #Aquí cada fila se irá metiendo dentro del array
        $arrayReuniones[] = $row;
    }
    #Mandamos un JSON, que es lo que el cliente espera
    echo json_encode($arrayReuniones);
}
```

Haciendo esto ganamos en simplicidad, en seguridad y en claridad del código.

Aún le faltarían algunas mejoras al código PHP, por ejemplo, debería preverse una respuesta para casos en los que no haya datos, o en los que la consulta o la conexión fallen, emitiendo quizá un JSON con una clave `error` en esos casos. Para dar coherencia al código, en el `done` de Ajax habría que verificar primero si la respuesta tuviera una clave `error`. Pero eso se aleja del problema inicial y lo dejo como observación para completar el código.

Espero sea de utilidad. Si no entiendes algo, lo puedes decir en comentarios.

Comment: Funciona perfecto y está clarísimo. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @InfiniteRoads me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente no lo veas igual que el tuyo pero es una estructura muy parecida, si tu puedes obtener del lado de Javascript tu arreglo, basta con iterar dicho arreglo con un `each`

Te recomiendo que mejor llenes un arreglo con tus datos que quieres obtener de tu consulta.

Archivo **.php**

```
function listar($data = array()) {
    $this->_data = array();

    $arrayReuniones = array();

    $consulta = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM reunion WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$fechaDesde' AND '$fechaHasta'");
    foreach ($consulta->fetchAll() as $reu) {
        $arrayReuniones[] = array( // aquí llenas el arreglo con los datos de tu consulta
            'id' => $reu['id'],
            'asunto' => $reu['asunto'],
            'fecha' => $reu['fecha'],
            'costo_estimado' => $reu['costeEstimado'],
        );
    }

    $this->_data = array(
        'arrayReuniones' => $arrayReuniones
    );

    print_r($arrayReuniones);

    return true;
}
```

Archivo **.js**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'listar',
    success: function (dataArray) {
        var data = dataArray.result.arrayReuniones;

        if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data.length > 0) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value.id);
                console.log(value.asunto);
                console.log(value.fecha);
                console.log(value.observaciones);
                console.log(value.costo_estimado);
                // en esta parte haces lo que quieras con tus datos que obtuviste en tu arreglo
            });
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Excelente le diste en el calvo, en el caso del porlbema, la causa es el objeto Reunion.

Comment: he intentado realizarlo como me lo planteas y sí que me devuelve un array mucho más claro pero me sigue dando error al intentar acceder a los valores. Edito pregunta para que lo puedas ver.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, en el código PHP en vez de utilizar print_r($respuesta), haz esto, convierte tu arreglo en json:

```
json_encode($respuesta);
```

Luego en el Js, accedes a los datos así:

```
success( function(resultado){

    let datosJson= JSON.parse( resultado);//la variable resultado, o sea lo que recibes
    //es solo una cadena, la cual debes parsear, convertirla a un objeto
    console.log( datosJson.arrayReuniones);//aqui ya puedes acceder a los fields
    }
    )
```